# UWSGI - 500s, appears overloaded

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I've built an application with Flask, and I've deployed it to servers with UWSGI and NGINX web servers on AWS.

I have 2 sets of servers, Web Servers and Application servers. Requests to the Application servers are proxied through the Web Servers.

When I do any number of API calls in a row, I start getting random 500s to some requests. I know the issue isn't related to my servers getting overloaded as I can see CPU Utilization running around 10%. I'm also pretty confident that the issue isn't related to my application code or database timeouts, as no matter how hard I try, I can't replicate the behavior on the Flask development web server.

I'm using UWSGI Emperor and checking the logs, I see no application/python errors. I just see the fact that a 500 is being returned. eg:

```
[pid: 2938|app: 0|req: 8/8] 86.40.78.178 () {42 vars in 1038 bytes} [Thu Sep 17 23:06:33 2015] GET /api/issue/231/workflow_items/ => generated 291 bytes in 84 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 6 headers in 557 bytes (1 switches on core 4)
```

As this is my first time working with UWSGI, I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong in terms of my configuration. Here's what my start up log looks like:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.1 (64bit) on [Thu Sep 17 23:06:20 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) on 17 September 2015 23:03:32
os: Linux-3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 14 23:43:07 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-10-0-1-90
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /var/www/workspace/venv/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 7826
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/www/workspace/workspace_uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:18:03)  [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/workspace/venv
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1b3bdc0
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 341832 bytes (333 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
added /var/www/workspace/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1b3bdc0 pid: 2933 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2933)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2938, cores: 5)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2939, cores: 5)
```

Here is what my UWSGI .ini looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/workspace

#python module to import
app = issuesite
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/workspace/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

processes=2
threads=5

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

and the upstart script for emperor:

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/var/www/workspace/venv/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log

exec $UWSGI --master  --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid nginx --gid nginx --enable-threads --logto $LOGTO
```

I saw something about `--thunder-lock` in the logs so I tried it but it made no difference, I still experience the same issues.

I wonder if anyone could give me some advice? I considered the possibility that the UWSGI is running out of memory? Note that using t2.micros on AWS.